# How to modify a DateInterval in PHP?

Tags: php

For instance, I can remove seconds from a `DateInterval` that is shorter than 24 hours like this:

```php
$di = new \DateInterval("PT3H20M10S"); // 3 hours, 20 minutes and 10 seconds
$diWithoutSeconds = new \DateInterval("PT" . $di->h . "H" . $di->i . "M");
```

However, this will create a new `DateInterval`, is there a way to modify an existing `DateInterval` instance, instead?

Comment: Have you used carbon?

Comment: Not sure if this is pseudo code, but it doesn't look like PHP.

Comment: Just set `di->s = 0;` ?

Comment: @NigelRen it was not PHP, right, now it is. (Sometimes it's too late to compose a SO question without running its code in a REPL session at least.)

Comment: @HonkderHase Great, I thought those fields are immutable. I think your comment is a good candidate for a simple accepted answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I only investigated the available methods on `DateInterval`, which was not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that seconds are not that important for your case, you might just ignore them. They're still needed to create an DateInterval though.

```
$di = new DateInterval('PT1H30M00S');
```

For existing date intervals, you can manipulate the object to "cut off" seconds.

```
$di->s = 0;
```

However, there's no need to manipulate the seconds.. when it's time for the output, you simply ignore the seconds - they're still there, but are not deemed significant.

```
$di = new DateInterval('PT1H30M25S'); // 1h, 30m, 25s
echo $di->format('%h hour(s), %i minute(s)'); // 1 hour(s), 30 minute(s)
```

The larger the interval is, the less significant smaller measurement units get.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was definitely necessary to cut off seconds, as I do some more time based calculations and rely on proper DateInterval objects.